# SignalR notifications not working. Is IIS required?

Tags: asp.net, signalr, asp.net-4.5

I am trying to execute a sample demo SignalR application as [shown in this post](http://ruchirac.blogspot.in/2014/10/get-database-change-notification-in.html).

When I am making database changes, notifications are not shown on browser. It remains a blank page.

Is IIS installation required for SignalR to work?

I am building on VS 2013 Community Edition with SQL Server 2012 Express. II8 Express is already installed.

In one other site it is suggested to use:

GRANT SUBSCRIBE QUERY NOTIFICATIONS TO "DOMAIN\ASPNET"

When I execute this, it gives error: Cannot find the user 'DOMAIN\ASPNET', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.

Which domain I need to mention?

I have also enabled BROKER from SSMS.

Comment: you want GRANT Notification to Domain User ? or IIS account ? . If is IIS account check your application pool name and enter Like "IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool" they is call ApplicationPoolIdentity .

Comment: i think that's your problem try it and report to me thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

SignalR can be hosted in IIS or it can be self hosted. I believe in that example you are trying to follow your best bet is to host it in IIS or you can run it in IIS Express or as stated part of a windows service which self hosts a SignalR hub. I actually worked on something similar where we used SQL Notification to update a grid via a SignalR hub. We ended up having to use Change Data capture instead of Sql Dependency because of the limitations with Sql Dependency.

Here are the [system requirements](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/supported-platforms) for SignalR hub